# How to grant privileges to a user for any firebird database

Tags: sql, firebird

I want to GRANT some privileges to a particular user in Firebird like we can do it in MySql as shown below.

```
CREATE USER 'user123'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user123pass'; 
GRANT CREATE, SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, DROP, UPDATE ON MyTestDb.* TO 'user123'@'localhost';
```

Is possible in Firebird?

Comment: Can't you try it to find out?

Comment: that's why I am asking I have tried it, but I am unable to do that.

Comment: I don't see that  information in your question anywhere. I see nothing about you having tried it, the results you got from that effort (including any error message), or anything else that would indicate you've done so.

Comment: Which version of Firebird are you using?

Comment: I am using Firebird 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You will need to grant privileges per table or view explicitly and individually.

See also the `GRANT` syntax in the [Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-privs) and the [Firebird 3 release notes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-access-sql)